# Is there a way to static_assert a variable reference given in a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, compile-time, static-assert

```cpp
struct Config 
{
    int version = 1; 
};

template<Config& config /* , ... */>
struct Peripheral
{
    const Config config_ = config;
    static_assert(config_.version > 1, "Config version must be greater than 1");
    /* ... */
};

Config myConfig;

int main()
{
    myConfig.version = 5;
    Peripheral<myConfig> peripheral;
}
```

I want to check at compile-time if the configurations given to my template are correct.

So I am trying to cast my reference to a constant instance in order to try to use it in my static_assert, but I get the error: 'invalid use of non-static data member ...'

Is there a way to check the values of a non-type parameter at compile-time in this case? Or do you have other suggestions to achieve this goal?

Comment: No, the variable could change after compile time

Comment: You make a change to `myConfig.version` that's only visible at runtime. Even in principle how would you expect that to be a valid argument to a compile-time `static_assert`?

Comment: Your `static_assert` would also require `config_ ` to be `static`. How else would it work? [like so](https://godbolt.org/z/d1cqv3qMr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the *value* of `myConfig` to be used at compile-time, then you should mark it `constexpr` and give it its value directly in the initializer. Whether it is a static or automatic storage duration variable is then secondary:

```
constexpr Config myConfig = { .version = 5 };
// alternatively before C++20 for example
// constexpr Config myConfig = { 5 };
/*...*/
Peripheral<myConfig> peripheral;
```

Then the template should take the parameter by-value, not by-reference, and you should use that template parameter directly in the `static_assert`:

```
template<Config config /* , ... */>
struct Peripheral
{
    static_assert(config.version > 1, "Config version must be greater than 1");
    /* ... */
};
```

Depending on what else is in `Config` or if you are not using C++20 or later, the type might not be allowed as by-value template parameter. In that case you can keep using a reference parameter (although I am not sure that this is good design) but you would need to make it `const Config&` instead to match the `const` implied by `constexpr`. In this case it does matter that `myConfig` has static storage duration (specifically it may be declared at namespace scope, as a `static` data member or since C++17 as `static` local variable).

If you want to keep on using a local `config_` copy to assert on, that copy should also be marked `constexpr` (`const` is not enough to make a variable usable at compile-time) and hence must also be marked `static` (because non-`static` data members cannot be declared `constexpr`).

The value of the template parameter and `static_assert` cannot be (potentially) determined at run-time, so `myConfig.version = 5;` will never work.

Comment: I'd probably just declare the `version` member as `constexpr`  because you don't know what else is in `Config`.

Comment: @Spencer You can't declare non-static data members as `constexpr` and I don't think marking it `static` matches the intended use of the `Config` structure.

Comment: @user17732522 Thank you so much for your answer! I have to use C++11, is there a way to implement your solution in this version?

Comment: OP's intended use isn't entirely clear to me. Of course you would mark it `static` and access it via `::` instead of `.`.

Comment: @Ghali I made some edits that I think should together give some idea of how to do it with C++11. Also, I think it would be helpful if your question clarified how you intend to use the `version` field in `Config`. Do you want to have multiple `Config` objects with different `version` values for different `Peripheral` specializations, or is there supposed to be only one value for `version` for `Config` throughout the program, but potentially multiple types with different `version`s? Some of the comments seem to assume the latter.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough on this point. I'm trying to have a config structure with a default set of values, which I could modify subsets of attributes by initiating different instances (one for each configuration).

Comment: @Ghali C++11 is still quite restricted by the way on the forms that may be used to do compile-time computation. For example if you don't want to simply initialize `myConfig` with aggregate initialization as I have shown, you will need a `constexpr` function which creates and returns the `Config` object, so that you can initialize `myConfig` from the return value, but in C++11 `constexpr` functions can have basically only a single `return` statement and nothing else, making it quite cumbersome to implement more complex computations. You should try to get at least C++14 working.

Comment: It could be that this is homework,  and the teacher imposed the "C++11 only" requirement.

Comment: So I finally went with the constexpr instances and with the designated initialization to change a subset of the attributes. Its works perfectly! Thanks a lot @user17732522 and Spencer for your help and your explanations!

Comment: @Ghali The designated initializers are C++20. Some compilers may support a non-standard variant before that, but it is a compiler-specific language extension (and might work slightly differently) in that case.